# how to convert the ssh-keygen generated keys into a format that Java can parse(just use java cann't us other material)

Tags: java, rsa, ssh-keys, public-key

I use ssh-keygen -t rsa generate a pair of RSAkey, but I cannot use it in my java program. how to convert it to the format that java can parse.I cannot use the terminal to convert it,  the transformation process needs to be implemented in Java code. Thank you

Comment: You need to provide more information. How are you trying to load the key? Are you trying to use Java's JCE API or are you using an SSH API? If so which, provide an example.

Comment: I am trying to load the key by String I want to convert it to privatekey